# OpenSSL stdin input is returning 'data greater than mod len' error, but the data can be decrypted from a file

Tags: powershell, encryption, openssl, stdin

In a powershell script, I'm trying to pipe in data (encrypted with public.pem) from a variable into OpenSSL and decrypt (using private.pem). But when the data is piped in, I consistently get the error 'data greater than mod len'. I know what this error means *generally* but it doesn't make sense here. Here are a few examples.

First, a "proof of concept" showing it works:

```
Set-Location $workingPath # this is the path where private.pem and public.pem are located

# this works
("Hello World for File" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey .\public.pem -pubin -out .\test.enc)
(openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey .\private.pem -in .\test.enc)
```

This works, and the decryption command will successfully show the contents of the original string. I feel like this shows that the encryption and decryption are working, and that the keys are valid for this purpose. It also shows that OpenSSL in general can accept data from stdin.

```
# these produces a 'data greater than mod len' error
$enc = ("Hello World for variable" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey .\public.pem -pubin)
($enc | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey .\private.pem)
(echo $enc | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey .\private.pem)
(echo "$enc" | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey .\private.pem)
```

If I eliminate the -out parameter it will place the results of the encryption into stdout and I can place that data into $enc

However, if I pipe $enc into openssl to decrypt I consistently get
`error:0406506C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:rsa_eay.c:508:`

```
# also produces a 'data greater than mod len' error
("Hello World for File for read" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey .\public.pem -pubin -out .\test.enc)
$fileData = (Get-Content .\test.enc)
(Get-Content .\test.enc | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey .\private.pem)
($filedata | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey .\private.pem)
```

Finally, if I first write the data to a file, then read that data, I get the same results. Whether or not I do it directly or first dump the data into a file.

What I have not included is any of the attempts with first encoding the encrypted data as base64 and then decoding it before attempting to decrypt it. It seems that *no matter what* I get this error when piping data in to decrypt.

The key pair is 4096 bit RSA generated with OpenSSL.

edit:
FWIW I get a similar issue piping input using AES

```
$symKey = '33333333333333333333222222222222'
$symIV = '1111111111666666'

# this works
("Hello AES" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -K $symKey -iv $symIV -out testAES.enc ) 
(openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -K $symKey -iv $symIV -in .\testAES.enc)

# produces "bad decrypt error"
# 83764:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:460:
$encAES = ("Hello AES" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -K $symKey -iv $symIV )
($encAES | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -K $symKey -iv $symIV )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several more hours of Googling I discovered that what I'm trying to do isn't possible the way I'm doing it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2#using-native-commands-in-the-pipeline

https://brianreiter.org/2010/01/29/powershells-object-pipeline-corrupts-piped-binary-data/